# Form within a form and a JSON call

Tags: asp.net, json, forms, jquery

In my page I have a form:

```
   <form method="post" id="confirm-order-form" name="confirm-order-form">
```

Inside the form I have written some scripts to make a JSON call:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
             if ($('#nlapproved').attr('checked')) {
                newsletter();
            }
        });

        function newsletter()
        {
            $form = $('<form action="http://mydomain.createsend.com/t/j/s/jtes/" method="post" id="subForm" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-name" id="hidName" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-jtes-jtes" id="hidEmail" />');
            $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="cm-fo-pikty" id="hidPrivateBusiness" />');

            $form
                .find("#hidName")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$context//checkoutinformation/info[key='name']/value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $form
                .find("#hidEmail")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$context//checkoutinformation/info[key='email']/value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $form
                .find("#hidPrivateBusiness")
                .val(']]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$acctype"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[');

            $.getJSON(
                $($form).get(0).action + "?callback=?",
                $($form).serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    if (data.Status === 400) {
                        alert("Error: " + data.Message);
                    } else { 
                        // 200
                        alert("Success: " + data.Message);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
    ]]>
    </xsl:text>
</script>
```

My problem is that this thing does not work when the outer form is there--the code works fine otherwise.
 Note: I am redirecting this page to another physical server in the post back of my outer form and i have a lot of other controls in my first form so i cant simply avoid that.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `$($form)`  The `$form` would imply that it is already a jQuery object, so why bother using a jQuery wrapper over it again?

Comment: Where is the redirect? Chances are you need to put it in your success callback, and you currently have it as the next statement after your `getJSON` in which case the redirect will happen immediately. getJSON is async

Comment: I agree with @asawyer, just use $`form.attr('action')`.

Comment: @BLSully :i am using xslt to make this url redirecting in my code.
Or more presisely this script is inside a form (   <form method="post" id="confirm-order-form" name="confirm-order-form">) this form will post back and my code inside the form will redirect the page

Comment: you cant take a form inside other , as far as I know , forms dont support nesting , but you can take two parallel forms ,and post them simultaneously

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid :can you please explain the second option a little more ,may be as an answer to the question?

Comment: Embedded forms are not valid in any W3C draft; if you really need a second form, append it to something else in the page that is outside the "main" form.

Comment: @TiesonT. I got a button inside first form and i need to submit second form in the same button click .can you explain a little more with your comment.

Comment: @AthulkSurendran : check this link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927618/is-to-possible-to-submit-two-forms-simultaneously

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid :i cant submit my parent form via ajax.I need to do a lot of stuff in that form ,as i had explained in my question including redirecting the page to another physical server.Actually i am doing this in a payment gateway integrated form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual form is being submitted.  Stop that:

```
$("#confirm-order-form").on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

EDIT: to submit ajax, then normal form:

```
...ajax.done(function () {
   $("#confirm-order-form").off('submit').trigger('submit');
});
```

After successful ajax completion, unbind the prevention of the form submission and trigger a submission.

Comment: :I know this will work but this is not the correct solution for my question ,I need to work both the forms.for i have other controls in my first form.

Comment: You need the first for to submit and the ajax form to submit simultaneously?

Comment: I need to submit ajax form first and ordinary form second.
I think this will solve the problem.i f any other suggestion please guide me.

Comment: everything works great except i have to click my submit button twice.in first click my child form works fine and in second click parent.I am not getting what is happening.can you please guide me.

Comment: @AthulkSurendran no, I'm not sure why that would be .. can you create a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

1) Add a `div` outside the form that has the `runat="server"` attribute.

```
<form runat="server">

    <!-- stuff here -->

</form>

<div id="target"></div>
```

2) Write your jQuery selector to target that div.

```
$('#target').append('<form id="newform"></form>');

// add your controls...

$.post(
    'your_action', 
    $('#newform').serialize(), 
    function(result){ 
        // handle result... 
    }, 
    'json');
```

3) Do whatever you need to do with the server form...