# How to submit two forms with one submit button with rails and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I need to allow a user to type up a comment and submit before asking them to provide account details. Once these details are provided, they are used to create a new user and the comment they wrote is also submitted and belongs to this new user. Currently, I simply can't figure out how to trigger the submit action on both forms, passing all the information to the server to carry these tasks out.

Basically what I want:

- User writes up a comment, submits
- Submit button displays a contact info form
- User fills this out, submits
- Data from both forms are submitted

What I have:

_feedback.html.erb

```
  <%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :input_html => { :maxlength => '500', :rows => '4', :placeholder => '...'}  %>
      <% if current_user.guest != true %>
        <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% if current_user.guest == true %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="contactDisplay()"></input>
  <% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.guest == true %>
  <div id="contact" class="post-contact">
    <%= simple_form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true }, defaults: { label: false, required: true }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :placeholder => 'Your Name', :id => 'name'} %>
      <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { :placeholder => 'Your Email', :id => 'email'} %>
    <% end %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitContact()"></input>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render 'posts/show/feedback' %>
```

posts.js

```
function contactDisplay(){
var contact = document.getElementById('contact'); 
    contact.style.display='block';
}

function submitContact(){
    document.getElementById("new_comment").submit();
    document.getElementById("new_user").submit();
}
```

Comment: you don't need two forms for this, why don't you do it with one?

Comment: You cannot submit two forms at once. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17541013/134115

Comment: @Ibu They are different models.

Comment: @Vaheh I figured this couldn't be done. My question is how to go about this. I appreciate the link, but it isn't very helpful as I'm not very knowledgeable on AJAX

Comment: You are going to have to use ajax on this one. it is pretty easy if you use it with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: As mentioned above, you can submit the contact form via AJAX and respond with a success message which includes user_id generated by rails. Then using javascript, populate a hidden field with user_id within the comment form and submit that form normally.

Another way as mentioned above would be to combine the two forms into one and do the user generation on the backend along with saving the comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested forms :) Here is a railscasts on how to do it 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1