# Two Forms one Submit Laravel form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and php and have been researching ways to submit different forms. The form I making now is a check box of interests that will submit to a follower table. So far I have it that each interest has it's specific value equal which will be used to display all articles associated with the interest_id.

Now I'm kind of stuck on the manner to submit the interests. I couldn't find any approaches of submitting multiple rows from one form. So now I made them multiple forms which works however I have to put a submit button on each.

Is there anyway to submit more than one form on a single submit button or a way to submit more than one row on one form?

Here is the code i have now...

**html:**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
    {!! Form::open() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('interest_id', '1', true) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    {!! Form::open() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('interest_id', '2', true) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form:: submit('Sumbit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

store function on my interestcontroller:

```
public function store(InterestRequest $interest)
{
    $interest = new Follower(array(
        'user_id' => $interest->get('interest_id'),
        'follower_id'  => Auth::id()
    ));

    $interest->save();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit two forms with one button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187028/javascript-submit-multiple-forms-with-one-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563299/submit-multiple-forms-with-one-submit-button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540875/submitting-2-forms-at-the-same-time-using-javascript