# how to post 2 different forms in a form on the same page action=""

Tags: php, html

So i have been stuck with this for about a day, thought maybe stackoverflow might be able to help.

i have a form  within that form there's a table and within that table each row (1-2) have forms that need to be posted on the same page. So far i've got the NiceHash form working although the post for the MPH does not seem to work no matter what work around i try. what i've tried to do so far [How to place two forms on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071250/how-to-place-two-forms-on-the-same-page) & [2 forms on same page php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381649/2-forms-on-same-page-php)

What i have noticed is in those posts they are posting to different pages, i am posting the data on the same page.

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
  <table class="table table-striped" style="width: auto;" id="api-table">
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 10px">ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th style="width: 15%;">BTC ADDR</th>
      <th style="width: 30%;">API ID</th>
      <th style="width: 22%;">API KEY</th>
      <th style="width: 40px">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td>nicehash
        <?php echo $userRow2[0]['company_name'];?>
      </td>
      <td>btc addy
        <p>
          <?php echo $userRow['user_btc'];?>
        </p>
      </td>
      <th>
        <form method="POST" action="">
          <p><input required="yes" type="text" name="nicehash_api_id" value="<?php echo $userRow['nicehash_api_id'];?>" placeholder="<?php if ($userRow['nicehash_api_id'] == NULL) { echo ' Enter NiceHash API ID';}  ?>" style="width: 50%;" /></p>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <p><input type="text" required="yes" name="nicehash_api_key" value="<?php echo $userRow['nicehash_api_key'];?>" placeholder="<?php if ($userRow['nicehash_api_key'] == NULL) { echo ' Enter NiceHash API Key';}  ?>" style="width: 100%;" /></p>
        </div>
        </form>
      </th>
      <td>
        <center>
          <?php
                      if ($userRow['nicehash_api_id'] !== NULL && $userRow['nicehash_api_key'] !== NULL) 
                      {
                        echo '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
                      } 
                      elseif ($userRow['nicehash_api_id'] == NULL && $userRow['nicehash_api_key'] == NULL) 
                      {
                        echo '<span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span>';
                      }
                    ?>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td>miningpoolhub
        <?php echo $userRow2[1]['company_name'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p> btc addy
          <?php echo $userRow['user_btc'];?>
        </p>
      </td>
      <th>NULL</th>
      <th>
        <form method="POST" action="">
          <p><input required="yes" type="text" name="mph_api_key" value="<?php echo $userRow['mph_api_key'];?>" name="mph_api_key" placeholder="<?php if ($userRow['mph_api_key'] == NULL) { echo ' Enter MiningPoolHub API Key';}  ?>" style="width: 100%;" /></p>
        </form>
      </th>
      <td>
        <center><span class="label label-danger">Disabled</span></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><button type="submit" name="mph-api-btn" class="btn">Update MiningPoolHub API</button></td>
      <td><button type="submit" name="nh-api-btn" class="btn">Update NiceHash API</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

This is the following code for post

```
    <?php

                  if (isset($_POST['nh-api-btn'])) 
                  {
                    $uid = $userRow['user_id'];
                    $api_id = strip_tags($_POST['nicehash_api_id']);
                    $api_key = strip_tags($_POST['nicehash_api_key']);
                    if ($userRow['nicehash_api_id'] == $api_id && $userRow['nicehash_api_key'] == $api_key)
                    {
                        $error = 'Error: NiceHash API ID & KEY already exists.';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       $idkey_check = @file_get_contents(utf8_encode('https://api.nicehash.com/api?method=balance&id='.$api_id.'&key='.$api_key));
                       if ($idkey_check == NULL)
                       {
                         $file_get_error = 'Network Error: oh Snap, we will be back shortly.';
                       }
                       $result = json_decode($idkey_check, true);
                       if (isset($result['result']['error']) == 'Incorrect key.') {
                          $ncheck_error = 'Invalid API ID or KEY.';
                       }
                       elseif (isset($result['result']['pending_balance']) !== NULL) 
                       {
                        if ($auth_user->update_nh_api_data($uid,$api_id,$api_key))
                        {
                        $success = 'Success: NiceHash API ID & KEY Updated';
                        echo "<script>$('#api-table').load(document.URL +  ' #api-table');</script>";
                        }
                       }
                  }
                  //::::::::: 
                   if (isset($_POST['mph-api-btn']))
                   {
                      $mph_key = $_POST['mph_api_key'];
                      if ($userRow['mph_api_key'] == $mph_key)
                      {
                        $mph_error = 'Error: API KEY Exists Already.';
                      }
                      elseif ($userRow['mph_api_key'] == NULL)
                      {
                        $key_check = @file_get_contents(utf8_encode('https://miningpoolhub.com/index.php?page=api&action=getuserallbalances&api_key='.$mph_key));
                        $encode = json_encode($key_check);
                        $decode = json_decode($e, true);
                        if ($key_check == NULL) {
                           $mph_error = 'Error: Invalid MiningPoolHub API KEY';
                        } else{
                            if ($auth_user->update_mph_api($userRow['user_id'].$mph_key)) {
                              $mph_success = 'Success: MiningPoolHub API KEY updated.';
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                   if(isset($mph_error))
                  {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $mph_error; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                   }
                  if(isset($ncheck_error))
                  {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $ncheck_error; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                   }
                  if(isset($error))
                  {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                   }
                  if (isset($success) || isset($file_get_contents)) { ?>
                                               <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; float: right;">
                                                   <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" >
                          <button type="button" style="color: white;" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Oops!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $file_get_error; ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;">
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" >
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Success!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $success; ?>
                        </div>
                                               </div>
                 <?php  } elseif (isset($success))
                  {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Success!</h4>
                            &nbsp; <?php echo $success; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php

                   }  ?>
```

I think i was catching on a bit of non-sense with the errors, was going to fix that after the forms started working.

Any clues on posting on the same page ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_REQUEST['form1'])) {
        //your code
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['form2'])) {
        //your code
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['form3'])) {
        //your code
    }

?>
<form action="">

    <form action="">
         <input type="submit" name="form3">
    </form>

    <input type="submit" name="form1">
</form>

<form action="">
    <input type="submit" name="form2">
</form>
```