# PHP registration bug and login issues

Tags: php, html

Can someone help me out? I don't know what's causing this, but if the person wants to register he first needs to do an attempt on logging in, before he can send a registration, idk. Can someone help me?
[Link](https://rageofnations.000webhostapp.com) to the problem- Stack says I need to add more code, but okay. If someone can help, can you please help me with the login form as well? most people on the internet who do this put login and register in different pages, cause that's easier for them, but I can't do it.
My full code-

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", ""); /*i removed these for stackoverflow post*/
if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Magebit login</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent Pro' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#move-left-btn").click(function(){
        $("#signup").fadeIn()
        $("#login").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#move-right-btn").click(function(){
        $("#login").fadeIn()
        $("#signup").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
    <script>
window.onload = function (){
document.getElementById('move-left-btn').onclick = function () {
 var targetClass = document.getElementById('Topdiv').classList;
  var addRemove = targetClass.contains('move') ? 'remove' : 'add';
  
 targetClass[addRemove]('move');
}
document.getElementById('move-right-btn').onclick = function () {
 var targetClass = document.getElementById('Topdiv').classList;
  var addRemove = targetClass.contains('move') ? 'remove' : 'add';
  
 targetClass[addRemove]('move');
}}
</script>
    <style>
    body { 
    padding: 2%;
    /*
    background: url(https://best-wallpaper.net/wallpaper/3840x2160/1609/Red-and-black-feathers-bird-tree-branch_3840x2160.jpg);*/
    background: url(https://best-wallpaper.net/wallpaper/3840x2160/1609/Red-and-black-feathers-bird-tree-branch_3840x2160.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    font-family: 'Advent Pro';
    }
  #blackdiv {
    position: relative;
 margin: 10.3% auto;
    height: 58%;
    width: 71.3%;
    background-color:#081f44;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
    #leftdiv {
        position: relative;
     float:left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        color:white;
    }
    #rightdiv {
        position: relative;
     float:right;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        color:white;
    }
    #Topdiv {
        position: absolute;
        margin: -2% 2.2%;
        height: 110%;
        width: 50%;
        background-color:white;
        color:black;
    }
    p1 {
         font-size: 25px;
    }
    p2 {
         font-size: 15px;
         line-height: 200%;
    }
    p3 {
         font-size: 15px;
         color:black;
    }
    #textleft{
        margin: 13% 20% 0% 17%;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #textright{
        margin: 18% 20% 0% 22%;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    #line{
       margin: -13% 0% 0% 0%;
        font-size: 30px;
        color:#42b0f4;
    }
    .button {
    background-color: #4286f4;
    color: white;
    padding: 3.5% 13%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 18px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:20px;
}
    .button1 {
    background-color: transparent; 
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #4286f4;
}
    .button1:hover {
    background-color: #4286f4;
}
    .button2 {
    color: white;
    padding: 4.5% 21%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color: orange;
}
    .button2:hover {
    background-color: #ffb435;
}
    #signup{
          position: absolute;
        margin: 11% 20% 0% 20%;
        font-size: 25px;
        display:none;
    }
    #login{
        position: absolute;
        margin: 17% 30% 0% 20%;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    input {
        width:120%;
        outline: 0;
        background-color:transparent;
        border-width: 0 0 2px;
        border-color: gray;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: orange;
}
i {
    color:black;
    margin: 0% -22%;
    float:right;
}
.background-container::after {
  display: table;
}
.background-container .Top {
  left: 46%;
  transition: right 0.5s ease-in-out,
              left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.background-container .Top.move {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#logo {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 14% 0% 0% 68%;
}
</style>
<div id = "blackdiv" class="background-container">
  <div id="leftdiv">
                <div id="textleft">
                <p1>Don't have an account?</p1>
                <p>
                <h1 id="line">____</h1>
                <p>
                <p2>This is a random text. This is a random text. This is a random text. This is a random text. This is a random text.</p2>
                <br>
                <button id="move-left-btn" class="button button1" onclick="moveLeft()">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightdiv">
            <div id="textright">
                <p1>Have an account?</p1>
                <p>
                <h1 id="line">____</h1>
                <p2>This is a random text. This is a random text. This is a random text. This is a random text.</p2>
                <p>
                <button id="move-right-btn" class="button button1" onclick="moveRight()">LogIn</button>
            </div>
        </div>
   <div id="Topdiv" class="Top">
            <img id= "logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/308wvqx.png" width="15%" height="15%">
            <div id="signup">
   <form class="modal-content" action="/register_success_page.php" method="post">
                <p1>Sign Up</p1>
                <p>
                <h1 id="line">____</h1>
                <p>
                <label for="name"><p3>Name</p3></label><i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf2c0;</i><br>
                <input type="text" name="name required/><br>
                <label for="email"><p3>E-mail</p3></label><i class="material-icons">&#xe0e1;</i><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" required/><br>
                <label for="password"><p3>Password</p3></password><i class="material-icons">&#xe899;</i><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" required/><br>
                <p>
                <button type="submit" value="signup" name="signup" class="button2" name = "signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
            <div id="login">
   <form class="modal-content" action="/login_success_page.php" method="post">
                <p1>Login</p1>
                <p>
                <h1 id="line">____</h1>
                <p>
                <p3>E-mail</p3><i class="material-icons">&#xe0e1;</i><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" required/><br>
                <p3>Password</p3><i class="material-icons">&#xe899;</i><br>
                <input type="Password" name="password" required /><br>
                <p>
                <button type="submit" class="button2" name = "loginbtn">Login</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" name="name required/><br>`

change this to

```
<input type="text" name="name" required/><br>
```

should fix the error as apparently name is not being sent properly.

```
ERROR: Pieteikšanās nav izdevusies INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('', 'x@y.com', 'ff'). Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are correctly registering users but you don't login them correctly, even there aren't login logic attached.

So I found another stack overflow answer for this question try it first [2 forms on the same page php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34381868/9535043)

**and make sure to implement your login logic.**

> and also you have to go with [bijay-regmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260790/9535043) answer